# Error while loading .Ko file to kernel

Tags: ubuntu

I have written simple driver and build it. When I tried to load driver I am getting below error
Insmod: ERROR could not insert module operation not permitted

Please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the right to load modules.
`sudo modprobe ...` should fix your *issue*